# Difference between window.history.back & parent.history.back

Tags: jquery

I was working on a website, where I need to go back to the page which I visited. I was using parent.history.back. And one of my friend suggested rather use window.history.back instead of parent.history.back. I'm still confused the difference. I hope I can get the exact difference between them.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`window` refers to the current frame, while `parent` refers the parent of the current frame.

So, use `window` in normal context. Use parent when dealing with `iframes`

If you don't have any `<iframe>` then go with `window.history.back()`

Comment: Thanks yaar. But, How can we have another page before parent? Parent means root webpage. Isn't it?

Answer (score 4):

> ***window.history.go*** has the parameter can either be a number which goes
>   to the URL within the specific position (-1 goes back one page, 1 goes
>   forward one page), or a string. The string must be a partial or full
>   URL, and the function will go to the first URL that matches the
>   string.
>
> For example:

```
window.history.go(-2) -  go back two pages:
window.history.go(1)  - go forward one page
```

> ***parent.history.back()*** acts like a simple back button. The result is
>   equal as if you clicked on the back browser button. There is have no
>   parameter to be passed. it never forward like window.history

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure they're the same.  I've played with history a fair bit, and it seems to be associated with the browser window, i.e. you get the same result if you go back (or forward) in the root window or in any iframe under it.

In fact you can get some seemingly odd behavior when you have multiple iframes, where going back in one iframe can change one of the other iframes in the window, because it's really calling the top `window.history.back()`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But, I'm here discussing about webpages. I don't have any iframes here. So, the answer is still same?

Comment: Yes, it is.  In fact in that case `window === parent` so it's all good.